remap the AltGr+; combination to dollar sign $
I want to use the AltGr+; combination to produce the dollar sign using AutoHotKey v2.0. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work after several failed tries. My keyboard has the actual AltGr key and I'm using the US keyboard layout.
These are the some of the scripts I've tried so far:
<^>!;::Send("$")
<^>!;::Send "$"
RAlt & ;::Send("$")
Since I'm not familiar with AutoHotKey, I used ChatGPT (which was very unhelpful) and the documentation. I also tried some simpler scripts (like <^>!k::l to produce l after pressing AltGr + k, which didn't work) just to see where is the problem exactly and I think that the system just doesn't recognize the AltGr key. However, when I write a script using RAlt, almost always I get some kind of an error.
Can anyone help me with the correct script?

This will bring clarity to your question about the ";" character and here are the operators for autohotkey.
You also should try claude ia for ahk v2, it's better than chat gpt.
^!;::Send("$")        ;  ^ = Ctrl | ! = Alt
RAlt & `;::Send("$")  ;  ";" must be scaped since it's a special character used to inline comments


Thanks. I used Claude and with its help I wrote the following script that works: >!;:: Send "$"
